# Issues related to Time in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a time constraint for creating slots in Django. 
The Code I have written is as below:

```
    start_time = request.POST.get('start_time')
    end_time = request.POST.get('end_time')
    dateTimeA = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H:%M')
    dateTimeB = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, '%H:%M')
    dateTimeDifference = dateTimeB - dateTimeA
    dateTimeDifferenceInHours = dateTimeDifference.total_seconds() / 3600

    if dateTimeDifferenceInHours <= 0:
        dateTimeB += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        dateTimeDifference = dateTimeB - dateTimeA
        dateTimeDifferenceInHours = dateTimeDifference.total_seconds() / 3600
```

I have some constraints as well:

**Constraint 1**: Timings: the user will give the timings varying from `5:00 AM to 4:59 AM`.

**Constraint 2**: End - Time cannot be after `4:59 am` of the next day.

**Cases:**

**Case 1:** creating slots from 2 am - 4 am should work fine.

**Case 2:** Presently, The code what I have written works incorrectly for case:

```
Start_time = 8:00
End_time = 6:00
```

Here, in front-end, the `start_time = 8:00` means morning and `end_time = 6:00` means the next day morning and violates our Constraint No:2.

**Case 3**: When someone gives `start_time = 5:00` and `end_time = 2:00`, we need to add the next day in end_time.

The Front-End Looks as below(The code is written in `HTML`):

[image]

So, if someone can please help with the improvements in the code I have written so, that all my above cases work properly.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, The problem is constraint 2 with the code I have written

Comment: Please __edit your question__ with those clarifications.

Comment: Please recheck the question. I have done it already

Comment: Indeed, sorry ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, it would be helpful for me if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

1/ the start time must be at least 5:00 (AM)

2/ a end time before 5:00 (AM) means "next" day

So

1/ a start time before 5 is wrong (simple)

2/ if you're endtime is before 5:00, it's a "next day" (simple)

3/ if it's after 5:00 AM (included) but before start time, it's wrong (simple)

4/ if it's after start time, it's assumed to be on the same day.

IOW, this should yield the expected results :

```
# mock Django's ValidationError
class ValidationError(Exception):
    pass

def check(start, end):
    # start: datetime
    # end: datetime

    if start.hour < 5:
        raise ValidationError("start time must be >= 5:00 AM")

    if end.hour < 5:
        # end hour < 5 means 'next day'
        end = end + timedelta(days=1)

    elif end.hour < start.hour:
        # unless it's between 0 and 4, end hour must be greater
        # than start hour
        raise ValidationError("end time must be either <= 4:59 or greater than start time")

    return start, end



# and the tests:

def test_ok():
    start = datetime(2020, 4, 29, 5, 0)
    end = datetime(2020, 4, 29, 7, 0)

    try:
        new_start, new_end = check(start, end)
    except ValidationError as e:
        assert False, "should not have raised {}".format(e)

    assert new_start == start, "s should equal start"
    assert new_end == end, "e should equal end"


def test_start_before_5():
    start = datetime(2020, 4, 29, 4, 50)
    end = datetime(2020, 4, 29, 7, 0)

    try:
        check(start, end)
    except ValidationError as e:
        assert e.args[0] == "start time must be >= 5:00 AM"
    else:
        assert False, "should have raised a validation error for start < 5"

def test_end_before_5():
    start = datetime(2020, 4, 29, 8)
    end = datetime(2020, 4, 29, 4, 59)

    try:
        start, end = check(start, end)
    except ValidationError as e:
        assert False, "should not have raised {}".format(e)
    else:
        endt = (end.year, end.month, end.day, end.hour, end.minute)
        expected = (2020, 4, 30, 4, 59)
        assert  endt == expected, "should have set end date on next day"

def test_end_after_5_but_before_start():
    start = datetime(2020, 4, 29, 8)
    end = datetime(2020, 4, 29, 6)

    try:
        check(start, end)
    except ValidationError as e:
        assert e.args[0] == "end time must be either <= 4:59 or greater than start time"
    else:
        assert False, "should have raised a ValidationError"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_ok()
    test_start_before_5()
    test_end_before_5()
    test_end_after_5_but_before_start()
```

As a side note, I very strongly suggest you use a Django `Form` (or `ModelForm` if appropriate) for your user inputs validation.

Comment: Case: Start-time: 2:00 am, End-Time: 4:00 am, Thus, the assumption in 1, I would say is incorrect.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood this part indeed xD.

Comment: Consider this just a simple scenario, we want a clock that starts from 5:00 am and end at 4:59 am of the next day. You can consider my code as well.